# How can I limit the size of a Mercurial log?

Tags: templates, version-control, mercurial

When I run Mercurial's "hg log" command from a terminal window, the results often fall off the screen, forcing me to scroll up to the top. As a result, I created a template to reduce the verboseness and format of the log:

```
[alias]
slog = log --template '{rev}:{node|short} {desc|firstline} ({author})\n'
```

However, I'd like to improve this even further by either a) limiting the size of the "slog" to just the last 10 commits or b) using a command like "hg slog ##", where "##" would be the number of logs shown in the results.

Any thoughts on how to achieve either A or B?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could define your alias to do only a fixed limit in this way:

```
slog = log --limit 10 --template "{rev}:{node|short} {desc|firstline} ({author})\n"
```

Or, you could put `--limit` on the end so that you can pass a number to it, as arguments to an alias will be appended to the end:

```
slog = log --template "{rev}:{node|short} {desc|firstline} ({author})\n" --limit
```

The above could be called like this for the last 10 changesets:

```
hg slog 10
```

You should also be able to define the parameterized version in this way, but it doesn't seem to be property expanding the `$1`:

```
slog = log --limit $1 --template "{rev}:{node|short} {desc|firstline} ({author})\n"

#I had to use shell execute to make it expand:
#slog = !hg log --limit $1 --template "{rev}:{node|short} {desc|firstline} ({author})\n"
```

Comment: Any thought on how to make "--limit" optional? If I type "hg slog", I'm not required to enter a value. It'd be nice if I could optionally do it.

Comment: Depends on your shell, but basically you will have to test if `"$1"` is equal to `""`. In Windows I would do `slog = !if "$1"=="" (hg log --limit 10) else (hg log --limit $1)` to make it work on one line with my limited batch file knowledge. (omitted templates for brevity)

Answer (score 7):

To get last 10 changeset:
`hg log -l10`

Alternative solution:
Configure [autopager plugin](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AutopagerExtension) in the `.hgrc` file.
The end result is similar to already mentioned solution

```
hg log | less
```

Comment: That is, `-l` (lowercase L) for limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a *nix environment, this allows you to scroll back through log history at your leisure:

```
hg log | less
```

or according to your preference:

```
hg log | more
```